# Facebook API for Android: ShareDialog closing Facebook unexpectedly

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use the new Facebook ShareDialog API in my App ...

I've created the App on Facebook to share the content ...

I'm Sharing the Content using the following code

```
private void shareOnFacebook(){
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
    .setLink(link).setDescription(sharemsg)
    .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

}
```

The link String is simply a "http://www.google.com.br" and the sharemsg is "hello world"

When sharing on my main facebook account it works fine, but no one can actually see what i'm sharing ...
And, when I'm sharing on any other the Facebook intent open really quickly and simply close after that returning to my app screen... 
No errors are actually being displayed too...

I've searched everywhere and no clue what it might be...

Also, the other parts of the code that I'm using Facebook, like the Login are working properly

Any clues??

Thanks!

Comment: Found the problem, looks like you can't use the ShareDialog on other accounts if the App on Facebook is on Developers Preview Mode ...